# How to make UIAnimation execute one at a time (iterate over for loop), instead of executing all at once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, mobile

I am currently creating a view controller for an app that helps visualize the Bubble Sort algorithm. However, when the user presses the sort button, instead of the swaps occurring one by one (giving the user some time to see how the algorithm works), the numbers sort all at once and they all go to their respective places all at once. I'm looking to get the UIAnimation to iterate over a for loop and have the elements in swap one by one, instead of all at once.

I have already tried passing a delay as a parameter to the UIView.animate method. All it does is pause the specified amount of time before sorting them all at once (which I do not want).

```
//IBOutlets for the images (containing numbers) and the sort button
@IBOutlet weak var sortButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var firstImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var fourthImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var fifthImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var sixthImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var seventhImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var eighthImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ninthImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tenthImage: UIImageView!


//Create an array of UIImageViews
var elements : [UIImageView] = [UIImageView]()
var numberArray : [Int] = [Int]()

//Function when the view loads
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Add the UIImageViews to the array
    elements += [firstImage, secondImage, thirdImage, fourthImage, fifthImage, sixthImage, seventhImage, eighthImage, ninthImage, tenthImage]

    //Create a variable that will indicate whether there is a duplicate number in the array
    var duplicate = true;

    //Assign each element in the array a random number between 1 and 10
    for index in elements {
        //Repeat-while loop to avoid duplicate numbers in the array
        repeat {
            //Create a random number
            let randNumber = Int.random(in: 1 ... 10)
            //Display the appropriate numbered image
            index.image = UIImage(named: "\(randNumber)")
            //Check to see if the number is already a duplicate
            if numberArray.contains(randNumber) {
                duplicate = true
            } else {
                duplicate = false
                //Add the number to the list of used numbers in the array
                numberArray.append(randNumber)
            }
        } while duplicate == true
    }
} //End of viewDidLoad




@IBAction func sortButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    //Bubble Sort algorithm
    for i in (0..<elements.count) {
        for j in (1..<elements.count) {
            if numberArray[j]<numberArray[j-1] {

                let temp = numberArray[j-1]
                numberArray[j-1] = numberArray[j]
                numberArray[j] = temp

                let tempElement = elements[j-1]
                elements[j-1] = elements[j]
                elements[j] = tempElement

                //Swap the corresponding UIImageViews on screen
                let tempView : CGRect = elements[j-1].frame

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0, animations: {
                    self.elements[j-1].frame = CGRect(x: self.elements[j].frame.minX, y: self.elements[j].frame.minY, width: tempView.width, height: tempView.height)
                    self.elements[j].frame = CGRect(x: tempView.minX, y: tempView.minY, width: self.elements[j].frame.width, height: self.elements[j].frame.width)
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to make the image swaps (animations) happen one by one (for each iteration) instead of all at once? (Area of focus is towards the bottom of the sortButtonPressed function...) Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: tried putting your animation code to be inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something like this manually you will need to start a new animation when current one finishes. There are few ways of doing that but one of them is to pack all data you need for your animation in a class and then create an array of such classes. You may then create a single method which is called recursively. Something like this:

```
- (void)performAllAnimations:(NSArray *)allAnimations
{
    NSMutableArray *duplicate = [allAnimations mutableCopy];
    AnimationDescription *currentAnimation = duplicate.firstObject;
    [duplicate removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:currentAnimation.duration animations:^{
        // Use currentAnimation to do the animation
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(duplicate.count > 0) [self performAllAnimations:duplicate];
    }];
}
```

You do not always need `AnimationDescription` as a custom class. In your case it might be enough to simply use an array of indices. For instance you would then do:

```
- (void)performAllAnimations:(NSArray *)allAnimations
{
    NSMutableArray *duplicate = [allAnimations mutableCopy];
    int currentAnimationIndex = [duplicate.firstObject integerValue];
    [duplicate removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        // Use currentAnimation to do the animation
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(duplicate.count > 0) [self performAllAnimations:duplicate];
    }];
}
```

You could then do something like:

```
NSMutableArray *indexArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    [indexArray addObject:@(i)];
}
[self performAllAnimations: indexArray];
```

Using your own data naturally.

Another approach is using a delay. For some cases it could be better as you have more control over when the next animation starts. See the following example:

```
- (void)performAllAnimations:(NSArray *)allAnimations withAnimationExecution:(void (^)(id animationObject, int index))execution
{
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0.3;

    for(int i=0; i<allAnimations.count; i++) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:(duration*0.5)*i options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            execution(allAnimations[i], i);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }
}

- (void)testAnimation
{
    NSMutableArray *views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
        [self.view addSubview:aView];
        aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        aView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
        aView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
        [views addObject:aView];
    }
    [self performAllAnimations:views withAnimationExecution:^(id animationObject, int index) {
        UIView *view = animationObject;
        view.frame = CGRectMake(75.0*index, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That makes sense and it worked. Thank you for the clear explanation!

Comment: @AK19996 Considering what you are building it might actually make more sense to use animation with delay. I edited my answer to add a full example of that as well. You should give it a try.